# Como alocar dinamicamente quando não sei quantas posições vou utilizar em C?

Tags: c, memória, alocação, array

Em uma parte do código preciso transformar um inteiro em binário e armazená-lo em um vetor de caracteres, porém, eu não sei qual inteiro vou receber para transformar em binário, então não sei quantas posições terá o meu vetor de `char`.

Como tratar este problema com alocação dinâmica? preciso alocar espaços na memória de acordo com a necessidade do meu programa, já que vou receber um `int` e preciso transformar esse `int` em binário, porém, desconheço os valores.

Comment: tenta `vetor[sizeof(int)*8]`, acho que assim da.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 8):

Um `int` terá (quase) sempre 32 bits, portanto você sabe o tamanho necessário. Mesmo que não saiba, em casos assim é melhor alocar o suficiente para o maior possível. Na verdade é algo tão simples que você não deveria alocar dinamicamente. Faça a alocação como vetor mesmo e não se preocupe com isto.

Conforme os comentários eu fiz um código para, pelo menos, demonstrar o funcionamento (como falta informação na pergunta, ele precisará de adaptações):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int inteiro = 3;
    int tamanho = sizeof(int) * 8; //aqui acha o tamanho de um int
    char binario[tamanho + 1]; //aqui aloca o vetor de char com espaço para o terminador
    int i = tamanho - 1; //inicia o contador
    while (i > 0) {
        binario[i] = inteiro % 2 + 48; //acha o binário
        inteiro /= 2;
        i--;
    }
    binario[tamanho] = '\0'; //coloca o terminador
    printf("%s", binario);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/gQguoI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qdqmarwy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Dinamically.c).

Note que ele não considera o [endianness](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_(ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

Comment: porém, se o número for 3, por exemplo, ficará 0000....00011. Como vou precisar concatenar estes vetores de char mais pra frente, não é legal pra mim ter um monte de zeros desnecessários...

Comment: Se ele é um `int` em binário ele terá 32 bits. Eu imagino que você vai colocar um bit em cada posição do *array*. O fato dos primeiros dígitos serem 0 não significa que ela não tenha todos eles. Você só vai preencher as 2 últimas posições do *array* com 1 e o resto com 0.

Comment: Bom, você já está mudando o problema. Quando você faz uma pergunta, você tem que dar detalhes. No caso você não falou o que ia fazer com isso. Ainda assim, eu faria desta forma. Pelo menos do jeito que descreveu o problema. Se você tem que fazer algo completamente diferente do que descreveu, aí provavelmente eu faria de outra forma, mas não tenho como saber, só posso falar sobre o que está na sua descrição. Da próxima vez que fizer uma pergunta, descreva corretamente tudo que precisa, coloque código que você já fez, isole o problema e mostre especificamente onde está tendo problema.

Comment: Se vai concatenar, muito provavelmente vai precisar destes zeros para manter as posições nos lugares certos, caso contrário vai acabar formando número errados. Não posso garantir isso, mas como eu disse, não está na descrição da pergunta como deve ser tratado esses casos. Na verdade a pergunta nem é sobre isto. è claramente sobre alocação apenas.

Comment: @bigown é o seguinte como está na minha resposta eu entrei com um numero muito alta com 11 digitos, e veirique o que o sizeof retorna, ele me retornou 8, siginifica 8 bytes, ou seja o sizeof(int) sempre retorna 4, mas ai surgiu minha duvida pois o inteiro tem um limite, la eu explico melhor

Comment: @Skywalker Acho que você mesmo já entendeu que um número muito grande vai necessitar um `long` e não um `int` que foi o que o AP pediu. Se está com alguma dúvida sobre o funcionamento disto, abra uma pergunta.

Comment: ok resolvido já. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

A solução do @Maniero resolveria.

Mas deixo a minha também.

Partindo do principio onde `sizeof(int)` -> devolve o numero de bytes que um tipo inteiro usa na memória, no caso retornaria 4, logo multiplico por 8 para termos em bits, e assim o resultado seria `32`.

```
int tamanho = sizeof(int)*8;//sizeof de int para independer da arquitetura 
 char vetor[tamanho];
```

Em relação aos zeros "desnecessários", fazer uma forma de removê-los seria um tempo gasto atoa, e se for caso de economizar espaço isso sim acharia desnecessário.