# Limite de conversão binário em C

Tags: c, tipagem, conversão

Desenvolvi esse código em C para conversão de inteiros para binário, porém o limite é de 1023. Qualquer número acima desse, a conversão deixa de ser realizada

Qual o motivo e possível solução?

```
int binario(int num) {

    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    return (num % 2) + 10 * binario(num / 2);

}

int main(){

    printf("%d",binario(7));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que está retornando um `int` que tem uma capacidade limitada. Eu mudei no código para usar `long` que permitirá números maiores. Mas tem limite também.

Então qual é o problema? Tentar fazer uma representação numérica como se ela fosse um número. O número é o número, você faz contas com ele. A representação numérica é o que você vê escrito. É um texto que por acaso tem dígitos numéricos escrito, mas aquilo não é um número.

Você não faz contas com representações. E mostrar o número em binário é apenas uma representação. Assim como o que você vê na tela normalmente é só uma representação decimal.

Se realmente deseja criar uma representação binária, gere um texto e não um número, mude o retorno para `char *` e codifique de forma apropriada para gerar o texto. Como foi feito em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83421/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>

long binario(int num) {
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    return (num % 2) + 10 * binario(num / 2);
}

int main() {
    printf("%ld", binario(1025));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FRZ5Ju). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iflvtqoc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/IntOverflow.c).