# Conversão de decimal para binário

Tags: c

Haveria um jeito de resolver esse problema usando apenas repetição, div e mod, sem usar vetor ou uma função específica para a conversão?

Comment: Uma opção é operações com bits. Como essa [solução elegante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911777/9719107).

Comment: A pergunta é ampla e fora de escopo, o objetivo do site não é fazer a tarefa das pessoas, além disso já foi respondida. Além do que pela pergunta não ser clara, fez de uma forma torta. As respostas na pergunta original fala disso. Não existe número binário. O que foi respondido aqui é uma atrocidade tentando fazer um número decimal parecer binário, mas isto está conceitualmente errado.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode implementar uma função para fazer essa conversão:

```
long dec2bin( long dec )
{
    int resto;
    long bin = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while( dec != 0 )
    {
        resto = dec % 2;
        dec /=  2;
        bin += resto * i;
        i *= 10;
    }

    return bin;
}
```

Código testado:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long dec2bin( long dec )
{
    int resto;
    long bin = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while( dec != 0 )
    {
        resto = dec % 2;
        dec /=  2;
        bin += resto * i;
        i *= 10;
    }

    return bin;
}


int main( void )
{
    long i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
        printf( "%ld = %ld\n", i, dec2bin( i ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
2 = 10
3 = 11
4 = 100
5 = 101
6 = 110
7 = 111
8 = 1000
9 = 1001
10 = 1010
11 = 1011
12 = 1100
13 = 1101
14 = 1110
15 = 1111
16 = 10000
17 = 10001
18 = 10010
19 = 10011
20 = 10100
21 = 10101
22 = 10110
23 = 10111
24 = 11000
25 = 11001
26 = 11010
27 = 11011
28 = 11100
29 = 11101
30 = 11110
31 = 11111
```

Comment: Não está muito correto isso. Veja o porquê [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184447/132).